# Invaild Output Error

Tags: c

I need to add two numbers. The constraint here is that i also have to check that the input is not an alphabet. I have used isdigit() function to check for this. But when i run the code it executes the else block even if the input is number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void main()
{
int a,b,c;
clrscr();
scanf("%d\n",&a);
scanf("%d",&b);
c=a+b;
if(isdigit(a) && isdigit(b))
{
printf("%d",c);
printf("\n");
}
else
{
printf("Inavild Output");
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: Mind pressing Tab/enabling automatic indentation in your editor, please.

Comment: @Anidh Singh  You have to read data as strings and then to try to convert them to numbers. The current your program does not make sense.:)

Comment: You need to check scanf to see how many items were converted.  Since you don't check, you have no way of knowing that any input is not an integer.

Comment: Compare the values of `isdigit(1)` and `isdigit('1')`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow how can i do that?

Comment: @AnidhSingh what type of inputs have you tried? Have you tried `!isalpha()` instead of `isdigit()`

Comment: @AnidhSingh In fact it is enough to check the success or failure of  scanf calls without using functions from <ctype.h> as for example isdigit.

Comment: Note: The `'\n'` in `scanf("%d\n",&a);` is certainly not doing what you expect.  Suggest dropping it and review `scanf()` documentation for details.

Comment: It's `int main(void)`, not `void main()` in C.

Answer (score 1):

The function `isdigit` expect an integer representation of a character (it's ascii value). You are giving real integer values, whose value probably is not a digit when checking the ascii table.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to take inputs from the user you would need to use char or string variable. It is much clearer. Like :

```
char input_a;
char input_b;
```

Secondly, you cannot add char values directly if what you want is the result of adding the digit not adding the Ascii representation for them. So the line c=a+b would need to be done after you have ensured input_a and input_b were in fact digits.

Thirdly, you need to convert input_a and input_b to the value they represent. So your "if" would look like this (note there are many ways to convert a char into an int) :

```
if(isdigit(input_a) && isdigit(input_b))
{
   int a = atoi(input_a);
   int b = atoi(input_b);
   int c = a + b;
   printf("%d",c);
   printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `int isdigit(int argument)` take integer argument as a parameter and check the
>   argument is a digit or not if it is a digit then return `1(true)` if
>   the argument is not a digit then it return `0(false)`.
>
> if you pass `int a = 65` to the function it will convert the value to
>   it's equivalent [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) Value and return the result `false(0)`. Because
>   `65` is equivalent to `'A'` and `'A'` is not a digit.

You can check it this way.`if(scanf("%d",&a) == 1 && scanf("%d",&b) == 1)`. If the input is number then calculate and print the `result,` if input is not number than it will print `Inavild Output.`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int a,b,c;
clrscr();
if(scanf("%d",&a) == 1 && scanf("%d",&b) == 1) //if numbers read condition will be true
{
    c=a+b;
    printf("%d",c);
    printf("\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Inavild Output");
}
getch();
}
```